# Python and ctypes: why printf("%f", 10.1) is wrong

Tags: python, printf, ctypes

i have a question about ctypes in python

```
from ctypes import *
printf = cdll.msvcrt.printf
printf("%s\n", "Hello World!")
printf("%d\n", 100)
printf("%f\n", 10.1)
```

Result:

```
Hello World!
100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Windows7\Desktop\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    printf("%f\n", 10.1)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
```

I know that how to correct the mistake: 10.1 should be replaced by `c_double(10.1)`, but why should I use `c_double()` function here? The  first two `printf` doesn't need `c_string()` or `c_int()` at all.

And what's more, it's "%f", not "%lf", so i think if i must use ctypes function here, i should use c_float() instead of c_double, but when i tried `printf("%f", c_float(10.1))`,  i got the wrong result: 0.000000, why?

Comment: Interesting: printf("%d\n", 100) displays a 0 for me, not 100 (Python 3.2.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `printf("%f", c_double(10.1))`

Explanation: `printf()` is a varargs function. The format parameters explain which type you can expect on the stack.

The problem: There is no way to distinguish between `float` and `double` arguments when looking at the format but `float` uses 4 bytes while `double` uses 8. So how can `printf()` tell which one has been pushed on the stack by the code?

Answer: `float`s are always converted to `double`. This way, all floating point types always use the same number of bytes on the stack and `printf()` can figure out their address.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,but I don't know the implement principle of **printf**, in my view, can't **printf** check the format parameters to determine whether float or double has been pushed on the stack? e.g if **printf** found the format parameter is `%f`, it would regard the additional arguments as a float, and if `%lf`, then regard as a double. Can't it do like this?

Comment: This is code from the 1970s. In that time, space was precious and everything afterwards had to be backward compatible. The original implementation only accepted double types for any of `%f`, `%e` and `%g`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string `l` only works for integer types.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [ctypes documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions) :

> None, integers, longs, byte strings and unicode strings are the only
>   native Python objects that can directly be used as parameters in these
>   function calls. None is passed as a C NULL pointer, byte strings and
>   unicode strings are passed as pointer to the memory block that
>   contains their data (char * or wchar_t *). Python integers and Python
>   longs are passed as the platforms default C int type, their value is
>   masked to fit into the C type.

So, you don't need to use c_int or c_string because those are "native" python objects.

For your second problem, [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders) :

> f, F : double in normal (fixed-point) notation. 'f' and 'F' only differs
>   in how the strings for an infinite number or NaN are printed ('inf',
>   'infinity' and 'nan' for 'f', 'INF', 'INFINITY' and 'NAN' for 'F').

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx) too that a "f" modifier is for a double type.

So, it looks like python-ctypes read the same documenation and consider that with a %f you have to give a double.

Comment: Thanks very much.But why i can't use `printf("%f", c_float(10.1))`  ?

Comment: @MarkZar : I found an explanation in Wikipédia as shown in my answer edition.